# unittest for a serialisation method

Tags: python, python-unittest, doctest

Just started learning/applying Unittest and I have this class method *save()*:

```py
class A():

    __file_path = "file.json"
    __objects = {}

    def save(self):
        """
        serializes __objects to the JSON file: __file_path
        Note:
        __objects is a dictionary of Keys: numbers
        .                            Values: object of class B with a get_dict() method returning dictionary representation a B.object
        """
        for k, v in self.__objects.items():
            Dict[k] = v.get_dict()
        with open(self.__file_path, 'w') as fd:
            json.dump(Dict, fd)
```

How to approach this method for a unit test?

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33184342/how-do-i-mock-an-open-write-without-getting-a-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Refactor: Pass in the open file (i.e. stream-like object) to the save method. Why does your object need to be aware of the file it is stored in?