# Again, how to use unittest.mock to test open(..., 'w') ... .write(...)?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am not trying to do anything practical here; I am just trying to understand how to use the `unittest.mock` module in this particular use case.  What I am attempting to do here is so simple, straightforward, and so smack down the middle of `unitttest.mock`'s wheelhouse that I can't believe I am having such a hard time getting it to work.

This toy example shows the problem:

```
def fn(in1, in2, out):
    with open(in1) as f1, open(in2) as f2, open(out, 'w') as f3:
        for line in f1:
            f3.write(f'1>{line}')
        for line in f2:
            f3.write(f'2>{line}')

from unittest.mock import patch, mock_open
from io import StringIO

in1 = StringIO('a\nb\n')
in2 = StringIO('c\nd\ne\n')
out = StringIO()
expected = '1>a\n1>b\n2>c\n2>d\n2>e\n'
expected_first_line = expected.splitlines()[0] + '\n'

with patch('builtins.open', new_callable=mock_open) as fake_open:
    fake_open.side_effect = [in1, in2, out]
    fn('this', 'that', 'somethingelse')
```

**Q:** I want to know **how must I modify** above script so that I can test whether or not `fn` wrote to the write handle the string stored in `expected`<sup>1</sup>.

I have tried to use the answers given in

[How do I mock an open(...).write() without getting a 'No such file or directory' error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33184342/559827)

...but they don't work at all.

For example, if I attempt to follow the first answer in the post above, by adding the following lines at the end of the script above:

```
handle = fake_open()
handle.write.assert_called_once_with(expected_first_line)
```

...the assertion never runs because the assignment on the first line bombs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/try.py", line 21, in <module>
    handle = fake_open()
  File "/opt/python3/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/unittest/mock.py", line 1075, in __call__
    return self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/unittest/mock.py", line 1079, in _mock_call
    return self._execute_mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/unittest/mock.py", line 1136, in _execute_mock_call
    result = next(effect)
StopIteration
```

If I follow the second answer, and add this line

```
    fake_open.return_value.__enter__().write.assert_called_once_with(expected_first_line)
```

...the test fails with

```
AssertionError: Expected 'write' to be called once. Called 0 times.
```

...which is a bit more civilized, but still pretty hard for me to understand.

Also, it appears that, once the function returns, the `out` variable can no longer be read.  (Every operation I've tried on `out` fails with a `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file` exception.)

Of course, I realize that I can roll my own mock object in 10-20 lines of code, but what I am trying to do here should be bread-and-butter for `unittest.mock`.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Even though in some of my attempts I used the value in `expected_first_line`, I am really not interested in testing just one line in the output, but all of it.  I hope that there is a straightforward way to do this.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set your mock to return 3 `StringIO` objects on 3 calls. These are ordinary `StringIO` objects that **do not track calls**.

You cannot assert that they had their `write` methods called in any particular way, because that info was never recorded. If you hadn't closed the files, you could check their contents:

```
# replace "assert" with an appropriate assertion method if you're using vanilla unittest
assert out.getvalue() == expected
```

but you closed the files, by using a `with` statement:

```
with open(in1) as f1, open(in2) as f2, open(out, 'w') as f3:
```

so the contents are gone, and there is no way to determine what, if anything, was written to them.

---

The most straightforward way to fix this would be to use a mock instead of a `StringIO` object for `out`. You can call your `fake_open` to create this mock (**before** setting `side_effect`) to get a mock file object with the standard `mock_open` conveniences, like `__enter__()` returning the same mock instead of a new one:

```
out = fake_open()
fake_open.side_effect = [in1, in2, out]
```

Then you can do things like `out.write.assert_called_with(whatever)`, or check `out.mock_calls`.